# DOM -- RE: Object Methods -- 'a method' or 'a function call'?

Tags: javascript, function, dom, methods

I am learning the DOM and trying to understand it based on my limited knowledge of OOP.

It is my understanding that a method is a function that is defined within an object.  Further, it is my understanding that a function is a block of code that is designed to perform a given task.  In order for the function to execute, it must be invoked by a function call, which may or may not pass an argument to the function's parameter, but in any case, triggers the function.

That said, if you consider `document.getElementsByTagName('p')`, why is it that we consistently call the `getElementsByTagName()` portion of the query "a method"?

The actual method is built in to the document object itself -- we don't see it, however, we do see the function call associated with the method when we query it with `document.getElementsByTagName('p')`. All documentation I've read, describes `getElemenstByTagName()` as "a method", when it's actually a 'function call' to a method.

[Element.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

In the example above, we set the argument of the "function call" to the tag name 'p' and which gets passed to the parameter of the document's built-in `'getElementsByTagName'` method.

What am I missing here?  Thanks in advance for your input.

Cheers!

Comment: "*defined within an object*" - not necessarily. It only need to be *called on* the object.

Comment: No, a method is nothing internal built inside the object. It's public, it's on the interface. In `document.getElementsByTagName()`, you are accessing the method from and calling it on the object.

Comment: @Bergi, ah, okay.  So in this example, the query does two things at the same time. It gets the method, and calls it? Please clarify if you will.  You say "you are accessing the method from and calling it on the object."  What are you accessing the method from -- the document object?

Comment: According to the spec, *"A function that is associated with an object via a property is called a method."* So irrespective of how it got there, a method is just a function that is accessed via a property, and `gEBTN` is accessed from the `document` object via a property.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the source of the confusion on my part.  Thank you Crazy Train.  I've be thinking of objects as being made up of properties AND methods, as two distinctly different things. Instead I should be thinking of objects as being made up of properties, some of which may be methods. W3schools says: "A JavaScript method is a property containing a function definition."

Comment: @efw Yes, (in JavaScript) `document.getElementsByTagName` is a property access like any other.